# Service locator vs IOC in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

i started developing xamarin app as hobby and i wondering why many xamarin application have implemented service locator instead of IOC container, which seems more clear to me. What are reasons behind this? is there any issues associated with ioc in xamarin applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues using either a `ServiceLocator` or `IoC` in Xamarin. You can even combine both, which many do.

Currently, Xamarin does not come with an IoC container, so you would have to build it yourself or use an external library such as:

- MvvmCross
- Xamarin.Forms.Labs
- Autofac
- TinyIoC
- etc.

It is difficult to say why Xamarin would chose a `ServiceLocator` over `IoC`. There is no official explanation, but one could be either preferences or codestyle.